# Alfresco Sync Groups: APIs and CMIS

Tags: api, synchronization, integration, alfresco, usergroups

We are doing Alfresco (Version 6.1) Integration with an ERP and we are almost finished but we have one problem.

We Sync sites/people/documents and groups from alfresco to our ERP (Odoo).

We don't have any issues with syncing sites/people/documents,

But for syncing groups it takes a lot of time because we have more than 100k groups.

For every single small change we need to load all 100k groups (40 MB of JSON) then we have to iterate over each group to sync its details and sync the members of the groups, I know details of groups don't change but we need

1. New groups created
2. Groups deleted from alfresco
3. Changes in group members (New members added/removed)

The groups matching the above conditions, we can call updated groups.

Is there any API that can send us only these updated groups?

Currently we are using /alfresco/service/api/groups API.

if someone has added a member to a group then all 100k groups are downloaded and iterated, which is really time consuming and foolish.

I am a python Developer, I have also tried cmis, and have been working on Alfresco since a few weeks, And a few days to find a fix for this problem.

Comment: How did you end up with that many groups?

Comment: Not sure, will ask the customer, but do you have any idea why there are many groups or why groups are created ?

Comment: Why aren't the users and groups in LDAP? Then you could use the LDAP sync that is already available out-of-the-box in Alfresco.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with audit log. See what is audited, and extend where you need (example, deleting groups). Then, instead of reading all groups simply track audit log.

https://docs.alfresco.com/6.1/references/dev-extension-points-audit.html

Comment: You could deploy your own implementation of the "node behaviours", calling whatever logic you may want on events that are of concern to you.

Comment: Maybe even something like this. https://github.com/jpotts/alfresco-kafka